# Make a dog command in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how to make a command that makes a `GET` request to [this dog API](https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random) and return the image in an embed. Here's the code I've tried:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
  name: 'afv!dog',
  description: 'Grab a cute doggo from dog.ceo',
  execute(msg, args, bot) {
    const prevmsg = msg
    const fetchEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#e3dcd3')
      .setTitle(':dog: Woof! Let me find you a doggo! <a:AFVloading:748218375909539923>')
      .setDescription("This shouldn't take long...")
    msg.reply(fetchEmbed).then(msg => {
      const { message } = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.text());
      console.log(message)
      const doneEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#e3dcd3')
      .setTitle(':dog: Woof! Found one!')
      .setImage(message)
      msg.delete();
      prevmsg.channel.send(doneEmbed);
    })
  },
};
```

This happens when I try to run `index.js`:

```
const { message } = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.json());
                          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `response.json()` instead of `response.text()`. `.text()` is for standard `html` plain text, however the dog API you are using returns an object.

Comment: Sorry for not including this, but when I tried this suggestion and the answer below, it came out with this. `const { message } = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.json());
                          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`
Sorry for not saying this, I have edited the question and have said this to the other answerer as well.

Comment: Change `execute(msg, args, bot) {` to `async execute(msg, args, bot) {` to make it `async`

Comment: @IceBotYT Could you provide more information on why it "didn't work"? Did you get the same error message?

Comment: Ah, my fault. Change `msg.reply(fetchEmbed).then(msg => {` to `msg.reply(fetchEmbed).then(async (msg) => {`

Comment: Sure. Let me try that.

Comment: Thanks!! IT WORKED!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

You're not awaiting `prevmsg.channel.send(doneEmbed);`, if I see it correctly

Edit: I am wrong

Comment: Sorry for not including this, but when I tried this suggestion and the answer below, it came out with this. `const { message } = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.json());
                          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`
Sorry for not saying this, I have edited the question and have said this to the other answerer as well.